# NSInvalidArgumentException from OIDAuthorizationService when using google signin in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, google-signin

I'm having a terrible day with this unfamiliar error

```
    2020-08-15 10:00:38.630941+0100 Wicrypt[44349:3718177] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[OIDAuthorizationService presentAuthorizationRequest:presentingViewController:callback:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x106b47af0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dfb4b2 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107a4b26e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e09f12 __CFExceptionProem + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107dff9e8 ___forwarding___ + 1479
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e01a18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Wicrypt                             0x0000000106aac8d2 -[GIDSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithOptions:] + 626
    6   Wicrypt                             0x0000000106aacd5f -[GIDSignIn authenticateWithOptions:] + 74
    7   Wicrypt                             0x0000000106aac59a -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 509
    8   Wicrypt                             0x0000000106aabde6 -[GIDSignIn signIn] + 64
    9   Wicrypt                             0x000000010671810b $s7Wicrypt18GoogleSignInScreenV4bodyQrvg7SwiftUI9TupleViewVyAE0J0PAEE5frame5width6height9alignmentQr12CoreGraphics7CGFloatVSg_AqE9AlignmentVtFQOyAE6SpacerV_Qo__AiEEAjklMQrAQ_AqStFQOyAE6VStackVyAGyAE4TextV_AZtGG_Qo_AuzE6ButtonVyAZGtGyXEfU_yycfU0_ + 91
    10  SwiftUI                             0x00000001095e1d91 $s7SwiftUI18WrappedButtonStyle33_AEEDD090E917AC57C12008D974DC6805LLV4BodyV4bodyQrvgyycAA09PrimitivedE13ConfigurationVcfu_yycfu0_TA + 17
    11  SwiftUI                             0x000000010989c000 $s7SwiftUI25PressableGestureCallbacksV8dispatch5phase5stateyycSgAA0D5PhaseOyxG_SbztFyycfU_ + 32
    12  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109657bac $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    13  SwiftUI                             0x00000001094dc901 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00000001094fbcd9 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA.1980 + 9
    15  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109657bcc $sytIegr_Ieg_TR + 12
    16  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109657bac $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    17  SwiftUI                             0x000000010964a791 $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    18  SwiftUI                             0x000000010964a044 $s7SwiftUI6UpdateO3endyyFZ + 436
    19  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109688a9d $s7SwiftUI19EventBindingManagerC4sendyySDyAA0C2IDVAA0C4Type_pGF + 301
    20  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109ac2a9c $s7SwiftUI18EventBindingBridgeC4send_6sourceySDyAA0C2IDVAA0C4Type_pG_AA0cD6Source_ptFTf4nen_nAA22UIKitGestureRecognizerC_Tg5 + 2060
    21  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109ac0782 $s7SwiftUI22UIKitGestureRecognizerC4send025_062C14327F4C9197D92807A7H6DF7F3BLL7touches5event5phaseyShySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCAA10EventPhaseOtF + 66
    22  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109ac15e3 $s7SwiftUI22UIKitGestureRecognizerC12touchesBegan_4withyShySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCtFToTm + 131
    23  SwiftUI                             0x0000000109ac0858 $s7SwiftUI22UIKitGestureRecognizerC12touchesEnded_4withyShySo7UITouchCG_So7UIEventCtFTo + 40
    24  UIKitCore                           0x000000011388b2f5 -[UIGestureRecognizer _componentsEnded:withEvent:] + 217
    25  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113dd2162 -[UITouchesEvent _sendEventToGestureRecognizer:] + 674
    26  UIKitCore                           0x000000011387f6fb __47-[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:]_block_invoke + 70
    27  UIKitCore                           0x000000011387f380 -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateForEvent:window:] + 489
    28  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d84bb8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4752
    29  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d5e7dd -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 408
    30  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113dee8c0 __processEventQueue + 15007
    31  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113de5398 __eventFetcherSourceCallback + 106
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d69b04 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d69a43 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 157
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d69187 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 222
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d63c68 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107d63542 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 538
    37  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111c15db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    38  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d4014e -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    39  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d451b1 UIApplicationMain + 101
    40  Wicrypt                             0x00000001066f786b main + 75
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010e009411 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[OIDAuthorizationService presentAuthorizationRequest:presentingViewController:callback:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x106b47af0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 732.7 - Device: iPhone 11 (7A79AEEA-ED4B-4DCD-BC33-81C73615B7A7) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A5332e) - DeviceType: iPhone 11
```

I have set the necessary delegate

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = googleDelegate
```

I have also set the presenting controller properly

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()!.presentingViewController = window.rootViewController
```

The closest resource I've seen is: https://openid.github.io/AppAuth-iOS/docs/latest/category_o_i_d_authorization_service_07_i_o_s_08.html#details

Please any help or reference will be resourceful

Comment: There is indeed no such method defined in the `OIDAuthorizationService` class https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/e191b1beadf3041259652e6e464eaceff16e5fbb/Source/AppAuthCore/OIDAuthorizationService.m#L317

Comment: Please update your post with the full crash call stack

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk I've updated the crash stack

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk I don't understand how AppAuth-iOS got involved in all these, I was just trying to implement Google sign-in on SwiftUi

Comment: AppAuth is the dependency https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleSignIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that is being called, is present in [this file](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/e191b1beadf3041259652e6e464eaceff16e5fbb/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDAuthorizationService%2BIOS.m#L31).

If your runtime can not find this method, it means that this file is not included into the project.

If you are using CocoaPods, this file [should be automatically included](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/2d83c4925710e7b0a5ebaa79918b265942831bb1/Specs/b/b/9/AppAuth/1.4.0/AppAuth.podspec.json#L41) for `ios` platform. Please insure that you specify

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

in your `Podfile`.

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it with pod and it works fine, I've been trying it all this time without pod

Answer (score 3):

This may be this necessary step from [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk?authuser=1) if you don't use pods:

```
Add the ObjC linker flag to the app target's build settings:

Other Linker Flags: $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC
```

Comment: It seems to be the correct solution when not using pods and if the AppAuth framework is already included. Setting `Other Linker Flags` in `Project > Build Settings > Linker` to `$(OTHER_LDFLAGS) -ObjC` solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to add -ObjC in OTHER_LINKER_FLAGS nor include AppAuthCore.framework in the app target's "Linked frameworks and libraries".

Adding AppAuth.framework alone is sufficient. (and in the associated carthage copy-frameworks Run Script phase.)"

(Based on the [ratkins' comment](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/issues/123#issuecomment-441661430) on AppAuth's Git forum)